# index backlog grows without reason?

Tags: magento2.3.3, index

We have the problem that some categories do not show products in the morning after an import via REST interface during the night.

So we had a look at `n98-magerun2 index:status`

The backlog grows and shrinks. How can that be if no products are currently being changed? Is there maybe some recursion?

```
#date; n98-magerun2 index:status
Fri Jan 31 09:47:31 CET 2020
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Title                           | Status | Update On | Schedule Status     | Schedule Updated    |
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Catalog Product Rule            | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (7 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:13 |
| Catalog Rule Product            | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:08 |
| Catalog Search                  | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (7 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:17 |
| Category Products               | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:06 |
| Customer Grid                   | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:06 |
| Design Config Grid              | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:06 |
| ElasticSuite Category Indexing  | Ready  | Save      |                     |                     |
| ElasticSuite Thesaurus Indexing | Ready  | Save      |                     |                     |
| Google Product Feed             | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (7 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:14 |
| Google Product Removal Feed     | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (7 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:14 |
| Inventory                       | Ready  | Save      |                     |                     |
| Product Categories              | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (9 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:08 |
| Product EAV                     | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (8 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:12 |
| Product Price                   | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (7 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:14 |
| Stock                           | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (6 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:47:12 |
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
#date; n98-magerun2 index:status
Fri Jan 31 09:50:17 CET 2020
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
| Title                           | Status | Update On | Schedule Status      | Schedule Updated    |
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
| Catalog Product Rule            | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (13 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:50:12 |
| Catalog Rule Product            | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog)  | 2020-01-31 08:50:08 |
| Catalog Search                  | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (12 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:50:15 |
| Category Products               | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog)  | 2020-01-31 08:50:06 |
| Customer Grid                   | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog)  | 2020-01-31 08:50:06 |
| Design Config Grid              | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (0 in backlog)  | 2020-01-31 08:50:06 |
| ElasticSuite Category Indexing  | Ready  | Save      |                      |                     |
| ElasticSuite Thesaurus Indexing | Ready  | Save      |                      |                     |
| Google Product Feed             | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (12 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:50:13 |
| Google Product Removal Feed     | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (12 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:50:13 |
| Inventory                       | Ready  | Save      |                      |                     |
| Product Categories              | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (16 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:50:08 |
| Product EAV                     | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (14 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:50:11 |
| Product Price                   | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (12 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:50:13 |
| Stock                           | Ready  | Schedule  | idle (13 in backlog) | 2020-01-31 08:50:11 |
+---------------------------------+--------+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a cron job that ran much longer than expected and was contiously updating products. That explains it.